# return a particular response to invalid presigned url aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I have an s3 bucket that users can access with a presigned url.
Due to some changes some users who are trying to access particular images will not be able to as their presigned url is invalid. I would like to respond to those requests with a particular image, essentially letting them know to update their application. Is their anyway i can achieve this? I cannot update their client directly so i need the change to be on the s3 or perhaps use cloudfront or something.

Comment: It sounds like you are using pre-signed URLs for long-term access? Normally, pre-signed URLs would be used within a short period (eg 5-15 minutes) of them being generated. Is your use-case different? If so, there might be a better way to achieve your objective, if you can tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

If the pre-signed URL is invalid, they will receive a standard `Access Denied` message.